# Теория графов. Поиск циклов длины 3 и 4

Tags: циклы, графы

Задан граф матрицей смежности. Необходимо найти циклы длины 3 и 4.
Матрица смежности возводится в степень 3 или 4... дальнейший алгоритм мне известен.
Однако препод в универе задаёт один вопрос: почему мы именно умножаем матрицы (возводим в степень), а не, к примеру, складываем их или умножаем на 3 или 4.
Буду признателен, если кто-нибудь объяснит этот момент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По индукции можно доказать.

Для самой матрицы смежности единицы стоят в ячейках, соответствующих путям длиной 1. Значит, свойство для степени 1 выполняется.

Пусть ячейки  матрица `B=A^n` содержат количества путей, т.е. `Bik` - количество путей из вершины `i` в вершину `k` длиной `n`. По определению при умножении матрицы `B` на `A` элемент матрицы `С=A^(n+1)`

```
 Сij = sum[k=1..size] Bik*Akj
```

а это сумма количеств путей длиной `n+1`, состоящих из путей длиной `n`из `i` в `k`, плюс количество путей длиной 1 из `k` в конечную вершину `j`. Итак, свойство сохраняется при увеличении степени матрицы.

Comment: благодарю, ответ понятен. Однако интересно, что будет при сложении матриц в ячейках полученной матрицы? В моём понимании, если матрицы сложить, то в ячейках будет просто информация о том, что из вершины i в вершину j существует ребро и это будет продублировано

Comment: Ну да, получается, что на каждую ячейку НЕ влияют другие ячейки при сложении, и нет физического смысла для количества путей при сложении,